# Normalizing huge numeric data to create a valuable line plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have the following dataframe:

```
Year           Month    Value
2005               9    1127.080000
2016               3    9399.000000
                   5    3325.000000
                   6    120.000000
                   7    40.450000
                   9    3903.470000
                   10   2718.670000
                   12   12108501.620000
2017               1    981879341.949982
                   2    500474730.739911
                   3    347482199.470025
                   4    1381423726.830030
                   5    726155254.759981
                   6    750914893.859959
                   7    299991712.719955
                   8    133495941.729959
                   9    27040614303.435833
                   10   26072052.099796
                   11   956680303.349909
                   12   755353561.609832
2018               1    1201358930.319930
                   2    727311331.659607
                   3    183254376.299662
                   4    9096130.550197
                   5    972474788.569924
                   6    779912460.479959
                   7    1062566320.859962
                   8    293262028544467.687500
                   9    234792487863.501495
```

As you can see, i have some huge values grouped by month and year. My problem is that i want to create a line plot, but when i do it, it doesn't make any sense to me:

```
df.plot(kind = 'line', figsize = (20,10))
```

[image]

The visual representation of the data doesn't make much sense taking into account that the values fluctuate over the months and years, but a flat line is shown for the most of the period and big peak at the end.

I guess the problem may be in the y axis scale that is not correctly fitting the data. I have tried to apply a log transformation to the y axis, but this don't add any changes, i have also tried to normalize the data between 0 and 1 just for test, but the plot still the same. Any ideas about how to get a more accurate representation of my data over the time period? And also, how can I display the name of the month and year in the x axis?

EDIT:

This is how i applied the log transform:

`df.plot(kind = 'line', figsize = (20,10), logy = True)`

and this is the result:

[image]

for me this plot still not really readable, taking into account that the plotted values represent income over the time, applying a logarithmic transformation to money values doesn't make much sense to me anyway.

Here is how i normalized the data:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df), columns=df.columns)
df_scaled.set_index(df.index, inplace = True)
```

And then i plotted it:

```
df_scaled.plot(kind = 'line', figsize = (20, 10), logy = True)
```

[image]

As you can see, noting seems to change with this, i'm a bit lost about how to correctly visualize these data over the given time periods.

Comment: Might be worth trying a logarithmic scaling on the y-axis by using something like `df.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20,10), logy=True)`

Comment: How exactly did you try to perform a log transformation and how exactly did you normalize the data? Please provide some code.

Comment: can you define y and x in your graph, you should take x as period and y as value, i don't understand why is y from 0 to 3, and what's with this peak?!

Comment: For a reference of example of logarithmic scaling, you can look at http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/2657838

Comment: Ok thank you guys, i'll edit the post to show what i've tried, but the `logy` argument don't change anything. Give me a minute

Comment: The post is now edited with the missing steps added

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one value is much much bigger than the others, causing that spike. Instead, use a semi-log plot

```
df.plot(y='Value', logy=True)
```

outputs

[image]

To make it use the date as the `x-axis` do

```
df['Day'] = 1  # we need a day
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])
df.plot(x='Date', y='Value', logy=True)
```

which outputs

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This seems like a more representative plot